# Should I always call ContainsData before I get data from the Clipboard?

Tags: c#, clipboard

After reading some MSDN posts on getting data from the clipboard, these posts seem to recommend calling the ContainsData method before getting data from the clipboard.

This seems to me to be a bit unnecessary and I am not sure if there is a good reason for doing this or if I have miss-understood the MSDN instructions.

[This MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> use the corresponding ContainsFormat methods first to determine whether data is available in a particular format.

[This MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdata(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Use the ContainsData method to determine whether the Clipboard contains data in the specified format or a compatible format before retrieving it

So here is my method:

```
// Should return null if no text is found on the Clipboard.
public string GetText()
{
    if (!Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Text))
        return null;

    // GetData returns null if the clipboard is empty of does not match the format.
    return Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
}
```

I realise I could be using `ContainsText` and `GetText` (although `GetText` returns `String.Empty` if no text is found - which is not ideal since then we don't know if it failed to get any text or if the clipboard really contains an empty string).

Anyway, a reviewer is asking me why I have the if-statement at all, and my response "because MSDN told me so" seems a little lacking in understanding (which I am).  Can anyone shed some light?  Do I need the if-statement?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to fix? Is it throwing an exception? *"then we don't know if it failed to get any text or if the clipboard really contains an empty string"* -- that suggests one reason why you might call `ContainsData()`: To find out if it's really there.

Comment: Can I remove the if-statement?

Comment: I don't read those MSDN comments as instructions or guidance for use, rather as snippets of ancillary information that help if you just want to peek at the clipboard.

Comment: I don't know, what happens if you do? Do you want `GetText()` to return null on "no text in clipboard", or an empty string?

Comment: Arggh, when the documentation explicitly advises adding race conditions to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really think you need it. Here is why:

> If this method cannot find data in the specified format, it attempts
>   to convert the data to the format. If the data cannot be converted to
>   the specified format, or if the data was stored with automatic
>   conversion set to false, this method returns null.

So it's basically telling you that it's because of robust programming. You have to get results consistent with your intents: getting a `null` from an object when that object isn't might lead to problems.

After further considerations, I realized the problem isn't in the if statement itself, but in the returned value, because the GetData method already return null if the data in the clipboard can't be converted, so it's redundant and might be de-facto unuseful, considering doesn't give any additional information whether the data couldn't be converted or is actually empty.

At this point I would write a method like this:

```
public bool isClipboardDataValid(out string _data)
{
    bool _isValid = false;
    if (Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        _data = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        _isValid = true;
    }
return _isValid;
}
```

and then call this method hence getting that extra information.

Comment: Also, _all_ objects have a `.ToString()` representation, so in the case of text, if it indeed tries to _convert_ (rather than just _cast_) any data to that format, you may get really weird results.